# Set Media dynamically for Django widget

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to add media inside `__init__` in a `Widget`?

I need to find language of page and pass it to widget, but it appears that middleware for processing request works after the media initialization.

So, basically what I have:

```
class SimpleMiddleware():
    # some code for getting language...


class MyWidget(Widget):

    class Media:
        js = (
            '//some source&language='+translation.get_language(),
        )
```

`translation.get_language` gives incorrect language, since the middleware didn't execute code before media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [set media as a dynamic property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/media/#dynamic-property):

```
class MyWidget(Widget):    
    def _media(self):
        return forms.Media(js=(
            '//some source&language='+translation.get_language(),
        ))
    media = property(_media)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because media=property(_media) makes it execute immediately.

Comment: It does? I wouldn't think that it would... defining a property doesn't ordinarily call the getter immediately.

Comment: I tested. It doesn't work. _media is called earlier than MiddleWare

Comment: Sorry, just forgot to restart server. Evertyhing works. Thank you:)

Comment: this version is outdated